# Kotlin do not call super

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin

I have a class that extends another, but in this class I do not want to call the super constructor.
How can I solve it?

Here is a snipet of my code

```
class SubarticlePagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, context: Context, var selectedArticleName: String) : ArticlePagerAdapter(fragmentManager, context) {

    var subarticleDao: ArticleDao
    var itemCount = 0

    init {
        ApplicationHelper().getApplication(context).appComponent.inject(this)
        subarticleDao = ApplicationHelper().getApplication(context).subarticleDaoSession.articleDao
        initBundles(context)
    }

    override fun initBundles(context: Context?) {
        }
    }
```

My problem, when this constructor is called, parent class constructor run first, and initBundles() will be called from there, but at that time subarticleDao and selectedArticleName are not set and I get exception.

Comment: I can think of two ways - you can create a secondary constructor and that doesnt do any fetch on the Dao and Name or add a additional boolean parameter in the ArticlePagerAdapter and if the boolean is false do not go inside the Dao and Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *TL;DR*

I'd advise you to move the code from the `init` block to the `initBundles` function and use your variables there after initialization. Then there would be no need to avoid calling the superclasses constructor.

### Extensive Answer

I think you should think about what you want to do with your design. Working around the idioms of a language is not very often a good idea or a sign of good design - at least when kotlin is your language :)

What you did with your code (overriding a - possibly abstract - method, `initBundles` from your superclass is pretty much the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). So it seems to me the purpose of `initBundles` is to let subclasses customize parts of the initialization... What basically is what you do in your init block.

*EDIT*: As Paul pointed out in the comments, you can't use the member `selectedArticleName` before your base classes initialization has finished. So if the base class calls `initBundles` during its initialization, then properties in the subclass won't be initialized as also stated at [Paul's link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order).

Since in the snippet you don't use `selectedArticleName`, you could just move your initialization stuff to the `initBundles` function and init your `subarticleDao` there.

However, if you *need* to use your subclasses properties at that point, I'd really advise you to rethink your design. There should be several ways to solve this, but to decide what would suits your requirements best one would need further insight into the intentions you have with your design.

Comment: While I completely agree with your approach there, you missed one detail. `selectedArticleName` (or rather the value thereof) can't be used in `initBundles` if it's called from the constructor or init block of a parent class. This is one of the rare cases, where kotlin is not `null` safe (see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order)).

Comment: You got me here. Just tried it and the value of a property passed in a subclass is indeed null during constructor initialization. I'll update my answer.

Comment: design choices aside, this answer doesn't actually answer the original question.  At all.

Comment: well, unfortunately you are right to some extent. this is because of the edits I had to make (see other comments). However, I do think that I proposed a valid alternative for the provided code (move `init` block to `initBundles`). Further, I wouldn't want to encourage trying to avoid calling the super constructor in Kotlin, this seems not to be intended by the language design.